# Some error in php function 

Tags: php, function

This Is my code
http://www.ideone.com/R1P4b

I'm use simple_html_dom class

In end of file
if i rung one line is no error and if i rung two line is return one error

```
echo getImg($text1) . "<br/>";
echo getImg($text2) . "<br/>";
error
```

but

```
echo getImg($text1) . "<br/>";
or
echo getImg($text2) . "<br/>";
```

Don't error

Please help me fix it

Comment: Why the hell do you nest functions?

Comment: What is with the *giant* HEREDOC statements?

Comment: in your code provided both $text1 and $text2 have the same HEREDOC name, could be relevant

Comment: error http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41W8UoporjL._SS500_.jpg

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare isbnfromtext() (previously declared in D:\www\www\download\cron\test\newEmptyPHP3.php:77) in D:\www\www\download\cron\test\newEmptyPHP3.php on line 77

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare the functions `isbnFromText()`, `isbn2Image()` and `imagePix()` **outside** of `getImg()`.

I don't know exactly how PHP handles functions that are declared inside another function, but apparently, it puts them into the same scope and if you run the outer function twice, they are declared again.

Example:

```
function a() {
    function b() {
        print 'foo';
    }
    b();
}
  
a();
a();
```

prints

```
foo
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare b() (previously declared in /t.php:4) on line 3
```

**Update:**

[Learn more about functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php), especially example 3. It is also stated there:

> All functions and classes in PHP have the **global scope** - they can be called outside a function even if they were defined inside and vice versa.
>
> PHP does not support function overloading, nor is it possible to undefine or redefine previously-declared functions.

Comment: @Thoman: What do you mean? Have you read the first sentence of my answer? Have you done it and still get the error?

Comment: Sorry because i don't see it :))